# Converting from ISO C timestamp to integer epoch in PHP

Tags: php, c, timestamp, iso

I have a timestamp:

2009-01-31T00:00:00

to which I am appending '+00:00' in order to get it to ISO C, from which I would then like to get the epoch, so I can feed it to date('...', timestamp) and generate the format I'd like.

What's the best way to go about this. I don't want to have to extract/string manipulation of the original timestamp.

TIA

Answer, Thanks shamittomar:

```
date('n/j/Y', strtotime($v['node']->field_pub_date[0]['value'] . '+00:00'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime). It parses about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

```
echo strtotime('2009-01-31T00:00:00+00:00');
```

This will show you the epoch as `1233360000`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$UST = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$dateObj = new DateTime($cellDataOfficeAttributes['date-value'], $UST);
list($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$second) = explode(' ',$dateObj->format('Y m d H i s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not shure if this is the best option but seams to give the right result

```
$str = '2009-01-31T02:20:50';
$time = strtotime($str);
var_dump(date('d-m-Y h-i-s', $time));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about http://php.net/strtotime?